# Debugger not coming to javascript written in usercontrol of visual webpart

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio

I had written some javascript and called rest api to get user profile in ascx file within visual webpart.

As attaching the process in VS with app pool and refreshing the browser does debugger to come automatically wherever debugger is written in javascript. But it is not happening this time in my case.

What will be the possible cause?

**Note:** Debugger is coming to server side code but not to javascript!